# Stone–Čech compactification as a semigroup

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, semigroups-and-monoids, stone-cech-compactification, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ be a topological group (we can assume that $G$ is countable and discrete) and let $\beta(G)$ be the Stone–Čech compactification of $G$. It is known that $\beta(G)$ can be turned into a left topological semigroup.

1. What are the invertible (left/right/both) elements of $\beta(G)$ as a semigroup?
2. Is right invertiblility the same as left invertibility? (That is, if $xy=1$ does this mean that $yx=1$?)

Comment: No element outside of G is left or right invertible if G is discrete.

Comment: The nonpricipal ultrafilters form a two sided ideal for any cancellative semigroup. See chapter 4 of Hindman and Strauss's book on Algebra in the Stone Cech compactification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Corollary 4.33 of Hindman and Strauss's book on Algebra in the Stone Cech Compactification says that if $S$ is an infinite cancellative (discrete) semigroup, then the nonprincipal ultrafilters in $\beta S$ form a two-sided ideal. In particular every left invertible element is invertible and the units of $\beta S$ and $S$ coincide. If $S$ is a group this means there are no left or right invertible elements outside of $S$.